# Java Regex to ignore specific word

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that ignores the occurence of certain word inside the input.

The regex works in a normal online regex tester but when I put it in java it doesn't match anymore

input string `IGNORE 23 55 21 66 IGNORE 55`

Regex: `((IGNORE)*)(\d{2})(.*)`

```
  final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "((IGNORE)*)(\\d{2})(.*)" );

  final Matcher m = p.matcher( "IGNORE 23 55 21 66 IGNORE 55" );

  final boolean b = m.matches();

  System.out.println( "matches = " + b );
```

The output is false

Comment: Where did you try this regex? and what's the expected output (as in the information you want to retrieve, or do you just want to test if it matches)?

Comment: **Use `m.find()`.**

Comment: Agreed with comment above - you can simply check string using .contains method and then parse it via the regex.

Comment: If you just want to extract part of a string after `IGNORE` word, you are doing it wrong, use: `final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "IGNORE\\s*(\\d{2})" );` and then  `if (m.find()) { System.out.println( "matched string = " + m.group(1); }`